# Ajax using jquery works on IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, rss

My end goal is to have a home page that pulls RSS feeds and displays them on my home page for my personal website. This is all done from the client side and I'm not looking to build a server site script to do this (I will though only if no other way is possible).

Below is the page load code. (I don't think this is a problem area but it nice to see the starting point)

```
 $(document).ready(function () { // Here
    loadpageF(); //<- problems is in this function 
    GetBackGround(document.body); //this just messes with the css of the site
});

function loadpageF() {
    addTableFeed("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1001");
    addTableFeed("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/odd");
    addTableFeed("http://www.nfl.com/rss/rsslanding?searchString=team&abbr=DAL");
    addTableFeed("http://www.npr.org/rss/rss.php?id=1007");


    $(".MainArea").css("width",$("iframe").length * (270));

}
//This function sets up where the RSS data will be place after formatting
 function addTableFeed(feedlink) {

    var numOfCell = maintb.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length;


    maintb.innerHTML += "<iframe id='f" + numOfCell + "' class='iframeFeed'></iframe>";

    getRSSFeed(feedlink, "f" + numOfCell);

}
```

This code basically calls a function for each rss to add and iframe and the passes the iframe id and the URL to another function (shown below and I am 99% sure is the problem) which getting the data.

```
 function getRSSFeed(feedlink, iframeid) {


     /*var xmlhttp; old way I did it below realizing it did not work in firefox

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            var hold = xmlhttp.responseText
            loadData(hold, iframeid);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("get", feedlink, false);
    xmlhttp.send();*/ //end of the old way

    //new way to try to use JSON of course failing at my in goal
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: feedlink,
        async: true,
        dataType: "text",   

        success: function(data){
            loadData(data, iframeid);
        },
        error: function(data, statusCode) {
            alert("ERROR: "+data.error)
        }

    });}
```

The function loadData works fine when called, however it is not called for the Yahoo.com and NFL.com feed. Instead I get an alert as shown below.

```
    //Note I has to transcribe from dialog box there may be errors
    ERROR: function () { 
    if( list ) {
        // First, we save the current length
        var start = list length;
        (function add( args ) {
            jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                ¡f( jQuery.isFunction( arg ) && (!options unique || self.has( arg)
                    list .push( arg);
                else if( arg  && arg.length ) {
                    // Inspect recursively
                    add( arg);
                }
                });
            })( arguments);
            //Do we need to add the callbacks to the
            // current firing batch?
            if (firing ) (
                firingLength = list length;
            //wiIh memory, if we’re not firing then
            // we should call right away
            J else if ( memory ) (
                firingstart = start;
                fire( memory);
```

Just in case it is needed, below is the load data code.

```
function loadData(xml, ifid) {
    var htmlStr;
    var artCount = 0;

    var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));
    $("#" + ifid)[0].contentDocument.open();
    $("#" + ifid)[0].contentDocument.close();
    $("#" + ifid)[0].contentDocument.write("<head><link rel='Stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" + document.getElementById("StyleSheet").href + "' /></head>");
    //RSS 2.0 handler
  $xml.find("channel item").each(function () {

        var $article = $(this);
        var title = $article.find("title").text();
        var description = $article.find("description").text();
        var link = $article.find("link").text();
        var pubDate = $article.find("pubDate").text();
        htmlStr = "<div id='" + artCount + "Span" + ifid + "' class='ArticalHead'><h3>" + title + "</h3></div>\n";
        htmlStr += "<div class='ArticalBody' id='" + artCount + "Div" + ifid + "'>\n";
        htmlStr += "\t<p>" + description + "</p><a href='" + link + "' target='_blank' > Click Here For more </a>\n";
        htmlStr += "\t<h6>" + pubDate + "</h6><br />\n";
        htmlStr += "</div>\n"


        $("#" + ifid)[0].contentDocument.write(htmlStr);

         $("#" + ifid).contents().find("#" +artCount + "Span" + ifid).click(function () {
             $("#" + ifid).contents().find("#" + $(this).attr("id").replace("Span", "Div")).toggle();
        });
        artCount++;
    });

    //Atom 1.0 handler
    $xml.find("feed entry").each(function () {

        var $article = $(this);
        var title = $article.find("title").text();
        var description = $article.find("summary").text();
        var link = $article.find("link").attr("href");
        var pubDate = $article.find("published").text();
        htmlStr = "<div id='" + artCount + "Span" + ifid + "' class='ArticalHead'><h3>" + title + "</h3></div>\n";
        htmlStr += "<div class='ArticalBody' id='" + artCount + "Div" + ifid + "'>\n";
        htmlStr += "\t<p>" + description + "</p><a href='" + link + "' target='_blank' > Click Here For more </a>\n";
        htmlStr += "\t<h6>" + pubDate + "</h6><br />\n";
        htmlStr += "</div>\n"


        $("#" + ifid)[0].contentDocument.write(htmlStr);

        $("#" + ifid).contents().find("#" + artCount + "Span" + ifid).click(function () {
            $("#" + ifid).contents().find("#" + $(this).attr("id").replace("Span", "Div")).toggle();
        });
        artCount++;
    });
    //$("#" + ifid).contents().find(".ArticalBody").hide();

}
```

Please forgive me for any typos or spelling errors. I can also post the whole web page if needed.

Comment: Only two of those URL's can be loaded, the other two are blocked by javascripts same origin policy, so they don't support CORS -> http://jsfiddle.net/F7xjT/

Comment: Is there away around this or do I have to make a server side page?

Comment: You'll have to use the serverside to get those links, as javascript can't do it.